# Does the node API allow for 90-character addresses (with checksums)

Tags: address, checksum

I have been examining the Jota IOTA library and see a lot of code that strips the checksums from addresses before hitting the node API. Would it be safe to say the 90 character addresses (with 9-character checksum) are only meant for users and not for usage by IoT devices and therefore should not be used with the node API?

Answer (score 4):

Correct, the checksums are intended only be part of the UX, and recently the IOTA team has made efforts to make the API consistent in only sending 81-character addresses to nodes, see [here](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota.lib.js/commit/6d9ae54fccc168d9ed757b06e5ea3d284715034c). This is not something there is an official source on, but something that has been confirmed in conversations with the main developers.

Comment: Yeah I've since figured out more about this. Examined all the places in the API where an address is used and they're all 81 characters. So I am not going to use 90 char addresses anywhere in my code unless it is to present an address to the user or to input an address from the user.

Comment: Yes, and if there is user input of an address, you should trim it down to 81 characters. This caused a difficult-to-locate bug in my code before I fixed it!